# Security risks for a simple network configuration screen in android

Tags: network, xss, android

I am building an Android App that pulls chart information from a server where the connection is specified on this view
[image]

Ideally, the end user will put in a valid host and port resulting in business as usual. However, I've recently been looking at Cross site scripting attacks. The example provided to me was that if a web page has a place where a user enters text, and the text collected from the end user is echoed (php) back to the screen, an attacker could write code to the web page and have it executed when the text is echoed.

My question is this: Can something similar be done here? Could an attacker write a script, append parameters, or something else that could otherwise compromise the Mobile device or the server we are attempting to contact? Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What I think you are saying is that an attacks success or failure depends on what we do with the host and port. Let's say we take no precautions to filter what is being typed in. We just perform a GET request on http:// + {Whatever host they typed} + : {Whatever port they typed} + /path/. could they type anything in there that would do anything more harmful than returning a bad request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the UI snippet alone, we cannot tell much, but given your pseudo-code of:

`http:// + {Whatever host they typed} + : {Whatever port they typed} + /path/`

You might be in danger of someone crafting the following input:

`http:// + {evil.com/evil_script.php?http://10.16.1.159} + : {8080} + /path/`

In this case, the `evil` script now can input to your website (given certain conditions).